# a way to simulate Union types without type operators

Tags: haskell

I have done this before using type operators, but I want to exclude those because I want to be able to do it with a smaller hammer, because I actually want to do it in another language, and I'm not too sure type operators do quite what I want.

The setup is two data types, Integer and...

```
> data Rational = Rational Integer Integer deriving Show
```

two type classes with sensible instances...

```
> class Divide2 a where
>   divide2 :: a -> a

> class Increment a where
>   inc :: a -> a

> instance Increment Main.Rational where
>   inc (Rational a b) = Rational (a + b) b

> instance Divide2 Main.Rational where
>   divide2 (Rational a b) = Rational a (2 * b)

> instance Increment Integer where
>   inc x = x + 1
```

I can define things that work instances of one type class or the other

```
> div4 x = divide2 (divide2 x)

> add2 :: Increment c => c -> c
> add2 = inc . inc
```

and then I want to take the union of these two data types...so the obvious thing to do is use a discriminated

```
> data Number = Rat Main.Rational | Int Integer
```

now...in my scenario, the functions that act on this union, exist in one distinct module (a binary, I'm not familiar with Haskells binaries)

but the data types themselves are defined in another

So clearly I can define some functions that (in principle) can potentially "work" on this union, e.g. functions that act on values of instances of Increment....and some that don't, e.g. one in Divide2

So how do I write a function, against this discriminated union, that applys a function to values in the union, that will compile for functions on Increment, but don't compile on functions on Divide2...I'll have a go here, and fall flat on my face.

```
> apply (Rat r) f = f r
> apply (Int i) f = f i
```

.

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Main.Rational’
                  with actual type ‘Integer’
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘i’
      In the expression: f i
      In an equation for ‘apply’: apply (Int i) f = f i
   |
86 | > apply (Int i) f = f i    |                       ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

as expected, the inference says its got to be an Rational because of the first call, but its an Integer...

but "clearly"...if I could make haskell suspect disbelief...like some sort of macro...then the function

```
> apply (Int 1) add2
```

does make sense, and moreover, makes sense for any value of Number I care to choose.

so the obvious thing to do is to make Number a member of anything in the intersection of the set of type classes each member is in....

```
> instance Increment Number where
>   inc (Rat r) = inc (Rat r)
>   inc (Int i) = inc (Int i)
```

and then ghc implements "apply" itself...I CAN as well map this solution back into other languages by some explicit dictionary passing...but I have hundreds, if not thousands of tiny typeclasses (I may even have to consider all their combinations as well).

so really I want to know is there some type magic (existential? rankn?) that means that I CAN write "apply" against Number, without resorting to some dependent type magic, or have to implement instances of type classes on the discriminated union.

P.S. I can do limited dependent type magic...but its a last resort,

Edit...

The code that contains the functions defined on Number can of course match the disciminated values, but if they do, then whenever union is extended, they will fail to compile (ok, they don't have to match each case individally, but unless they do, they can't extract the wrapped value to apply the function, because it wont know the type)

Hmmm...written down it looks like the expression problem, in fact it IS the expression problem...I know of many solutions then...I just don't usually like any of them...let me knock up the canonical Haskell solution to this using type classes.

Comment: It looks to me that you can simply declare `Main.Rational` and `Integer` individual instances of `Increment`, this is even a richer way to represent these, since know we "retain" the knowledge in the type system that the `inc` of a `Rational` is still a `Rational`.

Comment: I have havent I?....the point being is that the modules that define the functions, don't know if they are operating on Rationals or Integers ever, and over time, more "Number" types will be added, and when they are, you want to know which functions now fail (because the interesection of the typeclasses of each the wrapperd dicrimated types will shrink)

Comment: ah.....the above comment doest really make sense...of course it the function can look inside disciminatd union at any given point....but over time the union will grow, so if it does, the code will no longer compile....EVEN if in principle nothing else has broken.

Comment: MY comment...didnt make sense..yours did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept only functions that make use of `Increment` methods (and do not make use of any non-`Increment`al functionality) like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

apply :: (forall a. Increment a => a -> a) -> Number -> Number
apply f (Rat r) = Rat (f r)
apply f (Int i) = Int (f i)
```

You can now pass `add2` to `apply` if you like:

```
> apply add2 (Rat (Rational 3 4))
Rat (Rational 11 4)
```

In this *specific* case, implementing `apply` amounts to exactly the same thing as supplying an `Increment` instance for `Number` itself:

```
instance Increment Number where
    inc (Rat r) = Rat (inc r)
    inc (Int i) = Int (inc i)
```

...and now you don't even need the mediating `apply` function to apply `add2`:

```
> add2 (Rat (Rational 3 4))
Rat (Rational 11 4)
```

But this is a pretty special case; it won't always be so easy to just implement the appropriate classes for `Number`, and you will need to resort to something like the higher-rank types we used in `apply` instead.

Comment: ahha, so my expression problem answer sort of is correct, but I simply end up creating instances that are syntactically identical...let me try your answer, I think it may do exactly what I want, I assume rankN is very much a Haskell thing, there's no way to map this into industrial OO type systems?

Comment: hmmm...so actually this isnt quite what I'm after, not your fault, its quite difficult to explain, I want "apply" to allow ANY function that could be applied to Rat and Int...in my classic typeclass answer, I have to "prove" that the function can be applied by explicitly implementing it. In your example, you are showing that a specific precondition on any function means the function can be applied in general

Comment: I'll have a think about this...I may be asking for a contradictory thing..

Comment: @MrD The way that you convince the compiler that a function can be applied to both `Rat` and `Int` is by making it a typeclass method and making instances of that class for both `Rat` and `Int`. Once you've done that, you can add that constraint to the rank-2 type of `apply` and be on your way.

Comment: yep...I think I answered the typeclass bit, and you've answered the apply bit...as with a lot of these things the problem is actually trying to vocalise the question...I want various different functions to be defined against "Number"...when someone updates Number, without knowing anything about the functions or type classes...when a function project is recompiled it fail, if it cannot "work", I'll flag your answer as an answer..it IS to the question I've posed, but I'm not too sure I've asked the right question...I think I'll just have to try.

Answer (score 1):

So this IS the expression problem, so type classes solve this specific case.

you take the function you want to make general over some as yet undefined universe of types

```
> class Add2 a where 
>   add2' :: a -> a

> newtype Number' a = Number' a

> instance (Increment a) => Add2 (Number' a) where
>   add2' (Number' x) = Number' $ inc (inc x)

> three = add2 (Int 1)
```

and then make any type that inhabits the required preconditions in terms of type classes, inhabit the typeclass for your generalised "function".

you then implement your new "Number" data types, and create instances of them where they make sense.

Comment: I'll have to thnk about this.....I'm not sure if the problem hasnt just been kicked down the road, rather than solved.